# Changing member value from start() in Application and save reference to ui components

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, thread-safety, volatile

I have the following custom Application class implementation. However, I do not understand why the value of `isVisible` does not change. I tried to change the field type to `SimpleBooleanProperty`. However, it does not help. Also, I should access the ui later, so I wanted to save the reference to them, however, the value does not set as well. I tried initializing my ui components in start() method, however, after that if I see my field, it is null.

```
import javafx.stage.Stage
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean

class TestApplication : Application() {

    @Volatile
    private var isVisible = AtomicBoolean(false)

    override fun start(stage: Stage) {
        stage.show()
        println("Stage shown ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
        isVisible.set(true)
    }

    fun showUI() {
        Thread { launch(TestApplication::class.java) }.start()

        println("Waiting until getting visible")
        while (isVisible.get().not());
        println("isVisible=${isVisible}")
    }
}
```

Comment: `Application.launch()` creates a new instance of the `Application` subclass, and calls `start()` on that new instance. (What language is this, btw?)

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do here. You can only call `launch` once per JVM instance. Also, why not make `isVisible` a `val` and remove the `@Volatile` annotation? (@James_D It's Kotlin).

Comment: I just wanted to test resource sharing. It it Kotlin

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is creating the instance of the TestApplication class twice. `Application.launch()` creates new instance, does not get the existing one.

The solution can be to use singleton pattern on TestApplication class.